# Django ORM join on subquery

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have this two models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    value= models.FloatField()
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        Customer,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="orders"
    )
    

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True)
```

and i want to annotate the sum of total orders purchased by the customer, this could be done pretty straightforward with this query:

```
customer_total_subquery = Subquery(
            Customer.objects.filter(pk=OuterRef("customer"))
            .annotate(total=Coalesce(Sum("orders__value"), 0.0, output_field=FloatField()))
            .values("total")
        )

Order.objects.select_related("customer").all().annotate(customer_total=customer_total_subquery)
```

The problem is, for only 37000 orders, this query takes 4 minutes. Produced query:

```
SELECT "order"."id",
       (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(U1."order_value"), 0.0) AS "total"
        FROM "customer" U0 LEFT OUTER JOIN "order" U1 ON (U0."id" = U1."customer_id")
        WHERE U0."id" = "order"."customer_id"
        GROUP BY U0."id") AS "customer_total"
FROM "order" LEFT OUTER JOIN "customer" ON ("order"."customer_id" = "customer"."id")
```

We can see that there is a subquery that is executed once per row, so the customer_total subquery is executed 37000 times.

The ideal solution is to query only once and use this results to append on the main query, the query bellow takes less than  100 ms:

```
SELECT o.id, o.customer_id, subquery.customer_total
from order as o
         left join
     (
         select b.id, SUM(inner_order.value) as customer_total
         from customer b
         left join order inner_order on (inner_order.customer_id= b.id)
         group by b.id
     ) subquery on (subquery.id = o.customer_id)
```

Is it possible to achieve this query (join on subquery) using Django ORM?

Answer (score 0):

It could be done way easier and more efficiently, you can annotate your relation directly:

```py
Order.objects.select_related("customer").annotate(
    customer_total=Coalesce(Sum("customer__orders__value"), 
                            0.0, output_field=FloatField())
).all()
```

Quite the same query on two tables with 100k+ entries works for 500ms on my laptop (and most of the time was spent on data transfer).

By the way, your exact task is quite strange. I'm not sure why you think you need a `Customer` for each `Order` entry. You can collect all customers into a dict with ID as a key, and gather any information you need later. For example:

```py
customer_by_id = {c.id: c for c in Customer.objects.annotate(
    order_total=Coalesce(Sum("orders__value"), 
                         0.0, output_field=FloatField())
).all()}
```

Comment: It's strange because this query is a subquery of other queries that will result in data to a dashboard that will show the percentage of the customer in relation to the total of orders of all customers. Your second solution don't work cause i need the qs.

returning something like [{"commodity_1":89.10, "commodity_2": 10.21, ...}]

which represents the percentage of the total market cap that this customer holds in orders values. Your first example falls in the same problem, the customer_total is calculated for each row, and is taking 3 minutes+. you can check by viewing the resulted query.